# My android app is not opening but installing

Tags: android

I have developed my app for android version, everything is ready to launch the app but it seems that the app is running good on android studio emulator even my android device samsung j7 without any problem. But when I share my app to test with other android devices app is installing but when try to open  it is stopping unexpectedly which is really weird to me.

my minimum sdk target is 15 and maximum is 23 and sdk tool is 24.0.0 and my app size is about 19MB

Can anybody suggest me what should I do now.

Comment: Add the crash log.

Comment: try to debug and post the error.

Comment: the problem is in your code. This is the only answer you can get for the information you've provided

Comment: how r you getting its apk file?

Comment: I have generated signed apk file and it's size is about 19MB but when I upload this apk to google play store the app's size showing only 10MB, is that a problem or they compress the size after uploading the apk on store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable instant run in your Android Studio and Take a build once more. It will work fine.

Now, As per stable available version 2.1.2 of Android studio,

If you need to turn off Instant Run, go to

File → Settings → Build, Execution, Deployment → Instant Run and uncheck Enable Instant Run.

This occurs because The Apk provided for testing may be an instant apk.  So Disable it, Clean it and Build it once more. If its not a code issue it will work.