# NativeScript Android .aab/.apk published but app is not opening after installed

Tags: android, angular, google-play, nativescript, publish

Application: NativeScript + Angular + TypeScript

Platform   : Android

Problem:
During development everything works fine. By "ns run android", the app works perfectly on my android phone. So far so good, I created .aab package, and published it to Google Play Store, I can see the app in the store, and I'm able to download/install it to my android phone with no problem. Everything looks good up to this point. However, when trying to open the app, it just stops and disappear after less than a second, so it cannot be opened.

In order to understand the problem, I did more tests. (1) created .apk and published to Play Store, the problem remains exactly the same; (2) instead of publishing to Play Store, I transferred the .apk to the phone and installed it, while trying to open it, same problem.

It seems to be a problem with the .aab/.apk package, but I'm not able to figure out what's the real cause and how to get it resolved. I'm now kind of stuck. That's why I'm here to look for suggestions.

The command to build .aab

> ns build android --release --key-store-path mykey.keystore --key-store-password mypswd --key-store-alias mykey --key-store-alias-password mypswd --aab --copy-to app-release.aab

The command to build .apk

> ns build android --release --key-store-path mykey.keystore --key-store-password mypswd --key-store-alias mykey --key-store-alias-password mypswd --copy-to app-release.apk

Below are some solutions for similar problems, which I googled and tried, and unfortunately none works for my situation.
https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2668665?hl=en
[My android app is not opening but installing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39219217/my-android-app-is-not-opening-but-installing)
https://docs.nativescript.org/releasing.html#android-app-bundle
... ...

My environment:

NativeScript CLI: 8.1.5
Angular CLI: 13.2.2
Node: 17.6.0 (Unsupported)
Package Manager: npm 8.5.1
OS: win32 x64
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1301.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular   13.1.4
@angular-devkit/core            13.1.4
@angular-devkit/schematics      13.2.2 (cli-only)
@ngtools/webpack                13.1.4
@schematics/angular             13.2.2 (cli-only)
rxjs                            7.4.0
typescript                      4.4.4

Thanks,

Comment: It's a tough thing to debug, but maybe start by putting alerts at important breakpoints in your app initialization. It might also be that at initialization you rely on some features that should be handled differently - particularly if you're targetting sdk30 and the features are pre-sdk30.

Comment: Thank you Misha for the input! It seems that inspecting into the initialization is the only thing I can do in this situation. After flipped on/off quite some features, I found the problem was caused by '@nativescript/firebase-admob'. It works well during development. However, once gets built into .aab/apk, it simply breaks the app and makes the app not opening.

Comment: Does this help https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/issues/1808? See the discussion that followed

Comment: Hi Misha, it does talk about a same issue, even though it's about earlier version of admob. The current one is @nativescript/firebase-admob (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nativescript/firebase-admob), so I tried 
            >ns plugin remove @nativescript/firebase-coreb
            >ns plugin remove @nativescript/firebase-admob
            >ns plugin add    @nativescript/firebase-core
            >ns plugin add    @nativescript/firebase-admob
However, the problem remains the same. App works well for ">ns run android", but crashes at startup after installed via .aab/.apk.